# Understanding simplification of specific local optimality inequality

Tags: inequality, optimization, proof-explanation, convex-optimization

This might be trivial but I am struggling to justify the following simplification.
from:
$$ 
h(x^{*}+d) - h(x^{*}) \geq \sum_{j \not{\in} G} \nabla_jf(x^*)*d_j  + \gamma \sum_{j \not{\in} G}|d_j|
$$
to:
$$ 
h(x^{*}+d) - h(x^{*}) \geq -\max_{j \not{\in} G}| \nabla_jf(x^*)|\sum_{j \not{\in} G}|d_j|  + \gamma \sum_{j \not{\in} G}|d_j|
$$

**Specifically, why is there a negative in front of the maximization?**

Note:
I can get behind the fact that $$\sum_{j \not{\in} G} \nabla_jf(x^*)*d_j \geq \max_{j \not{\in} G}| \nabla_jf(x^*)|\sum_{j \not{\in} G}|d_j|$$ provided the jacobian is nonnegative element-wise. But then why add the negative sign?

Reference: http://www.optimization-online.org/DB_FILE/2017/03/5930.pdf (page 5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $a \ge - |a|$ for all real number $a$, we have
$$\sum_{j \not{\in} G} \nabla_jf(x^*) d_j \ge \sum_{j \not{\in} G} \Big(-|\nabla_jf(x^*)| \, |d_j|\Big) $$
$$= \sum_{j \not{\in} G} \left[-\Big(\max_{k \not{\in} G}| \nabla_kf(x^*)|\Big) \, |d_j|\right] 
+ \sum_{j \not{\in} G} \left[\Big(\max_{k \not{\in} G}| \nabla_kf(x^*)| - |\nabla_jf(x^*)|\Big) \, |d_j|\right]$$
$$\ge \sum_{j \not{\in} G} \left[-\Big(\max_{k \not{\in} G}| \nabla_kf(x^*)|\Big) \, |d_j|\right]$$
$$=  -\left(\max_{k \not{\in} G}| \nabla_kf(x^*)|\right)\left(\sum_{j \not{\in} G}|d_j|\right)$$
where we have used
$$\max_{k \not{\in} G}| \nabla_kf(x^*)| - |\nabla_jf(x^*)| \ge 0, \quad \forall j \notin G$$
in the 2nd line.

Comment: Yes, You have answered my question, thanks. Though I'm not sure about your second line. The following - sum(abs) >= -sum(max(abs()) only holds in the event all elements are non negative. Use the gradient vector [-5 3] and you will see. I'm okay with the assumption that is must be nonnegative, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing a generalization over all possible gradients.

Comment: @alexandregg For the second, just $- |\nabla_jf(x^*)| \, |d_j| \ge -\left(\max_{k \not{\in} G}| \nabla_kf(x^*)|\right) \, |d_j|$, or you can rewrite it as $(\max_{k \not{\in} G}| \nabla_kf(x^*)| - |\nabla_jf(x^*)| ) |d_j| \ge 0$ which is true since $\max_{k \not{\in} G}| \nabla_kf(x^*)| - |\nabla_jf(x^*)|  \ge 0$ and $|d_j| \ge 0$ (for all $j\ne G$).

Comment: thanks for the clarification

Comment: @alexandregg You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{j\notin G}{\nabla_jf(x^*)d_j}\geq\max_{j\notin G}{|\nabla_jf(x^*)|}\sum_{j\notin G}{|d_j|}$$ is not true.  For example, let $G=\emptyset$, $f(x)=-x$, and $d_1=1$.  Then $$\sum_{j\notin G}{\nabla_jf(x^*)d_j}=-1\cdot1=-1$$ but $$\max_{j\notin G}{|\nabla_jf(x^*)|}\sum_{j\notin G}{|d_j|}=|-1|\cdot|1|=1$$

Comment: True, I mentioned this under the nonnegativity assumption. To generalize it, it must be a >= -|a|, which explains the negative sign.